# How could I use operators from PHP in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a field as such in `PHP`:

```
return [
    'text1' => [
        'control' => [
            'text' => [
                'show_if' => [
                    'field' => 'text2',
                    'comparison' => '===',
                    'Show text 1'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'text2' => [
        'control' => 'text'
    ]
];
```

In theory `text1`'s control (a form) should only show if `text2`'s value is ever `Show text 1`, but I'm baffled as to how I'd transfer this relationship from PHP to JS.

I can't use `eval`, since that's evil, but is there no way for me to practically transform the code?

In other words, I'm trying to get PHP to tell JS to do:

```
(if text2 !== 'Show text 1') {
 //Don't show text 1
}
```

Comment: Very vague but `echo json_encode($array);` ???

Comment: You want to establish this condition in JS?

Comment: @nice_dev Yes, indeed.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The problem is not sending this array, not sure how you got the idea from the question. The problem is how do I get JS to do `(if text2 !== 'Show text 1') { //don't show text1`

Comment: Ahhh so you want some to write JS code though you haven’t shown how in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a map of operator to function which performs the operation.
e.g. :

```
const conditions = {
  '===': (a, b) => a === b,
  '!==': (a, b) => a !== b,
  'count': (a, b) => a && a.length === b,
};

const cond = conditions[condition];
if (!cond) {
  throw new Error('Unknown condition: ' + condition);
}
if (cond(a, b)) {
  // Matches
}
```